# Slicing columns from a dataframe with range and specific columns selected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slice

We know we can slice dataframe columns using loc and iloc functions. But our need to select some columns out of a dataframe can be complex. It can involve various number of columns in case of a dataframe with too many columns. Mentioning names or index number of each one of them may not be good for code readability.

To slide a range of columns:

```
df.loc[:,'col1':'col5']
df.iloc[:,0:5]
```

To select specific columns:

```
df.loc[:,['col1','col3','col7']]
df.loc[:,[0,2,6]]
```

But what if we want to do this both?

Say we need to select these columns `[1,3,7,8,9,10,11,12,17,18,19,20,26,40]`

Writing all these columns names or indices specifically is one way. Is there any other (shorter) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can mix the range function and list addition to do this without writing each and every column name or index.

```
df.iloc[:,list(range(7,13))+list(range(17,21))+[1,3,26,40]]
```

This way we can mix ranges in the columns and adding specific columns to the list of selected columns for the iloc function.

Answer (score 0):

We can do:

```
f = df.columns.get_loc
df.iloc[:, np.r_[f(1), f(3), f(7):f(9), f(10):f(12), f(17):f(20), f(26), f(40)]] #get both single cols and ranges of cols
```

Note we can also use columns names, e.g. f('Col1name'):f('Col5name').

Also remember that `iloc` is exclusive of last term (in above example the last column returned will be 'Col4Name'), whereas `loc`is inclusive of last term (last column specified will be included in selection).

Comment: True about iloc vs loc. Though, in the example, first column starts as col1. So both of that will return same thing.